# How to properly make changes to a parent NSManagedObjectContext that get merged into a child context?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a question about handling parent and child `NSManagedObjectContexts`.

I made the main context (the one XCode sets up automatically in a `CoreData` project) accessible like this: `App.managedObjectContext`

Say, I create a child `context` to be used in a detail view that shows and edits some data, for instance:

```swift
let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
context.parent = App.managedObjectContext
context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true

let detailVC = DetailVC(context: context)
// present(...)
```

Let's say, inside the `detailVC` you want to make changes globally (so that `App.managedObjectContext` is changed and the changes are merged into the created child context)

I could simply do it like this:

```swift
// Example:  App.managedObjectContext.delete(/*some object*/)
try? App.managedObjectContext.save()
```

This works and the changes are merged into the child context. But this executes the save on the main queue. Shouldn't I always change stuff on a background queue? My usual approach would be:

```swift
// Get the persistent container whose `viewContext` is App.managedObjectContext
App.appDelegate.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (privateContext) in
    // Do changes
}
```

However, these changes are not being merged into the child context. How can I do it?
My idea was something like this:

```swift
let newChild = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
newChild.parent = context.parent

// As I understand it, perform() will run on a background queue in this case, right?  
newChild.perform {

    // Example modification:
    // let object = newChild.object(with: civilization.objectID)
    // newChild.delete(object)

    try? newChild.save()

    newChild.parent?.perform {
        try? newChild.parent?.save()
    }

}
```

This seems to work but does this have any side effects or drawbacks? And is it actually running on a background queue?

(I've read the article on `NSManagedObjectContext` and learned some things, but this is still not clear to me: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext)

Thanks!

Comment: Think about what you're trying to achieve and think about how this affects overall app performance... so why would you need to execute a call to `save` using a private queue on a background thread if you're only saving the information relating to one entity? The User Interface  operates on the main thread. Background threads are available to perform processes that take time - processes that would otherwise "block" (cause to slow, stutter or stop) the UI responding. A single save to your main context on the main thread is a very fast and simple transaction and is unlikely to block your UI.

Comment: This simple save is an example. I'm interested in the general case. What if I had expensive changes?

Comment: The simple save is all you mention in your question. If that is not the intent of your question, then I would ask that you please update your question.

Comment: I changed the last bit of code to clarify it's an example